# Using a cache key based on user login

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, ehcache

I have a SpringBoot + Security + EhCache project.  There is a wrapper class (LoggedUserInfo) around SecurityContextHolder and a service to deal with User information:

```
public LoggedUserInfo {
    public static String getLogin() {
        return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
    }
}

public UserService {
    //(...)

    public User getLoggedUser() {
        var login = LoggedUserInfo.getLogin();

        return getByLogin(login);
    }

    @Cacheable(value = "userByLogin", key = "#login")
    public User getByLogin(String login) {
        return userRepository.findByLogin(login);
    }
}
```

My cache is configured as:

```
<cache alias="userByLogin">
        <key-type>java.lang.String</key-type>
        <value-type>com.myproject.User</value-type>
        <expiry>
            <ttl unit="hours">24</ttl>
        </expiry>
        <resources>
            <heap unit="MB">1</heap>
        </resources>
</cache>
```

The cache for *UserService::getByLogin* is working fine. I would like to do the same to *UserService::getLoggedUser* but based on the current user login.

After reading [cache](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) and [spel](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) docs I figured out It would be possible with something like this:

```
@Cacheable(value = "userByLogin", key = "T(com.myproject.LoggedUserInfo).getLogin()")
public User getLoggedUser() {\\...}
```

or:

```
@Cacheable(value = "userByLogin", key = "T(com.myproject.LoggedUserInfo).login")
public User getLoggedUser() {\\...}
```

But if I try to do that there is a warning every time *getLoggedUser* is called and the cache is never used:

```
WARN  o.e.i.i.store.heap.OnHeapStore - Max Object Graph Size reached for the object : [B@28c27a2f
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try bumping up the max object graph size *(default: 1000)*.

You can tune it like so:

```xml
<cache alias="userByLogin">
        <key-type>java.lang.String</key-type>
        <value-type>com.myproject.User</value-type>
        <expiry>
            <ttl unit="hours">24</ttl>
        </expiry>
        <resources>
            <heap unit="MB">1</heap>
        </resources>
        <heap-store-settings>
            <max-object-graph-size>10000</max-object-graph-size>
        </heap-store-settings>
</cache>
```

Comment: This solves the problem but I preferred to change the heap limits based on entries and not memory usage (see my answer).

Comment: Perfect! If you could mark any of the answers as accepted it'd be good. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

After reading [this](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3/issues/1955) I solved the problem changing my cache config to limit by number of entries instead of memory usage:

```
<cache alias="userByLogin">
        <key-type>java.lang.String</key-type>
        <value-type>com.myproject.User</value-type>
        <expiry>
            <ttl unit="hours">24</ttl>
        </expiry>
        <resources>
            <heap>150</heap>
        </resources>
</cache>
```

I still can not understand why the previous one worked with *UserService::getByLogin* but not with *UserService::getLoggedUser*.